# How to get latest value from state? react reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm firing a few actions that modifies the state, but when i want to use it to make an api.patch call, the updated values isn't there yet. Could you tell me why is that?

Inside my component:

```
const {userLevel} = useAppSelector(state => state.study);

              <CustomButton
                width="100%"
                onClickHandler={() => {
                  dispatch(studyActions.finishStudying());
                  dispatch(modalActions.toggleModal());
                  if (totalStudyTime && knownWords && unKnownWords) {
                    dispatch(
                      setLevelOfKnowledgeForUser({ levelOfKnowledge: userLevel.currentLevel })
                    ).unwrap();
                    navigate('/');
                  }
                }}
              >
                End
              </CustomButton>
```

Inside my studySlice -> reducer:

```
finishStudying: state => {
  if (state.wordSet) {
    const isMedium = calculateLevelOfKnowledge(
      state.wordSet.easyWordsNumber,
      state.wordSet.mediumWordsNumber,
      state.userLevel.answeredEasyWords,
      state.userLevel.answeredMediumWords,
      90,
      50
    );
    const isBeginner = isMedium ? false : true;
    const isIntermediate = calculateLevelOfKnowledge(
      state.wordSet.mediumWordsNumber,
      state.wordSet.hardWordsNumber,
      state.userLevel.answeredMediumWords,
      state.userLevel.answeredHardWords,
      50,
      40
    );
    const isAdvanced = calculateLevelOfKnowledge(
      state.wordSet.mediumWordsNumber,
      state.wordSet.hardWordsNumber,
      state.userLevel.answeredMediumWords,
      state.userLevel.answeredHardWords,
      90,
      50
    );
    if (isMedium) state.userLevel.currentLevel = 'medium';
    if (isBeginner) state.userLevel.currentLevel = 'beginner';
    if (isIntermediate) state.userLevel.currentLevel = 'intermediate';
    if (isAdvanced) state.userLevel.currentLevel = 'advanced';
  }
},
```

The last 4 lines of code are setting user's currentLevel.

I attached screenshot with current state after firing "finishStuding" action:
currentLevel is "początkujący" which is "beginner" in english.

[image]

But then when i want to use another async action (asyncThunk with api.patch call)
my current level is "". Could you tell me how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`useSelector` data is returned async.

Just try `getState` from;

```
const { getState } = useStore();
```